# How would I make a wifi alarm clock?

Tags: wifi, ios, apple-homekit

I was just wondering how I would create a completely custom wifi alarm clock, what are the things I would need in terms of IoT? I would want to control it via a custom built ios app. I am trying to model it based of the lifx system. I do know I would require an API, just not sure about everything required.

Btw I am a 14 year old just learning things, any advice would be highly appreciated!

Thanks,
Amman

Comment: first you have to define clearly what a wifi alarm clock is and how it behaves

Comment: Hi Amman, please add a bit more information of what parts exactly you want to use and what you want to achieve. Please add those information with [edit]. You can also take the [tour] to learn more about good questions on this site.

Answer (score 1):

The fundamental structure of the LiFX system, and roughly speaking, most of these IoT systems is as follows:

Device <-> Cloud <-> User

The device (the alarm clock) establishes and maintains a connection to a custom server in the cloud, informing the cloud of its state (connected, on/off, time). The cloud presents an API which user applications (eg. the iOS app) can use to query or command the cloud. A query might be "list my clocks" and a command might be "set time on clock 1 to 12:00". The cloud decodes the message, figures out which device to send a message to and sends the message.